# Entity Framework 6 with Mysql "System.InvalidOperationException"

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework-6

I'm new with .net
I'm trying building console app with EF6 and MySql

i always got this error when running it
[image]

this is my app.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=192.168.1.212;port=3306;database=zkatt;uid=fanta;password=040506"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description="MySQL Database Provider" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

my context class

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=MyContext")
    {
    }
```

anything i miss?

*edit
this is full report error
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall EF6 and MySql nuget packages ?

Comment: yes, i have try it. I have try to search all over the google for 6 hours, nothing work

Comment: Try writing `base("MyContext")` instead of `base("name=MyContext")`

Comment: @KaranDesai same error

Comment: okay now try putting your connection string in there and let me know whether it worked or not

Comment: @KaranDesai base("server=192.168.1.212;port=3306;database=zkatt;uid=fanta;password=xxx") same error

Comment: are there more than 1 config files in the same assembly? and are these nuget packages there: Mysql.Data and Mysql.data.entity?

Comment: @KaranDesai what u mean by more than 1 config file?

Comment: More than 1 app.conf in same assembly

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hk8t2e and http://prntscr.com/hk8t93 and http://prntscr.com/hk8tdp @KaranDesai

Answer (score 1):

Remove the useless node :

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description="MySQL Database Provider" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

And specify version of your `MySqlClient` provider like :

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
```

Comment: <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider> same error

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade mysql entity to 6.9.10, now its work, wasted my 6 hours.